# Explanations of OCaml Warnings

Tags: ocaml

I've been reading through the [list of OCaml warnings](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html) and am unsure what some of them mean (no examples are provided). Specifically, I'd like to understand:

Examples of code that trigger the following warnings (I think my interpretation of what each warning means is different from what it actually means because I am finding it difficult to produce cases that trigger the warnings that aren't outright language errors):

```
5.  Partially applied function: expression whose result has function type and is ignored.
6.  Label omitted in function application.
28. Wildcard pattern given as argument to a constant constructor.
59. Assignment to non-mutable value
```

What an "ancestor variable" and an "extension constructor" are:

```
36. Unused ancestor variable.
38. Unused extension constructor.
```

What these mean:

```
61. Unboxable type in primitive declaration
62. Type constraint on GADT type declaration
```

Comment: An example for each warning would really be a valuable resource, I think. But I suspect many of them are quite technical and hard to elicit. So they might not be of general interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complete the list:

28. A wild card pattern can be used as argument of an argument-less constructor

    ```
    type t = A
    let f x = match x with A _ -> 0
    ```

> Warning 28: wildcard pattern given as argument to a constant constructor

36. This warning is raised when one names an inherited class without using it:

    ```
    class c = object end
    class d = object
       inherit c as super
    end
    ```

> Warning 36: unused ancestor variable super.

38. An extension construction is a constructor added to an extensible sum type like `exn`

    ```
    module M:sig end = struct
      type exn += Unused
     end
    ```

> Warning 38: unused exception Unused

61. With recent versions of OCaml, it is possible to avoid boxing record with only one field or variant types with one constructor. This unboxing currently requires an annotation

    ```
    type t = I of int [@@unboxed]
    ```

However, the default representation may change in the future.
This change is transparent except for the FFI. Which means that external are paticularly brittle if they involve type without an annotation:

```
  type t = I of int
  external id: t -> t = "%identity"
```

> Warning 61: This primitive declaration uses type t, which is unannotated and
>   unboxable. The representation of such types may change in future
>   versions. You should annotate the declaration of t with [@@boxed]
>   or [@@unboxed].

62. Type constraints does not apply on GADT arguments when defining a variant type. For instance, in

    ```
    type 'a t = 
    | A: 'a -> float t 
    | B of 'a
    constraint 'a = float
    ```

> Warning 62: Type constraints do not apply to GADT cases of variant types.

The warning explains that `B []` is an error, whereas `A[]` is fine.

59. This warning is an internal flambda warning, which warns that a value that flambda conjectured to be non-mutable was, in-fact, mutable. This warning should not be raised in normal circumstances.

Comment: Regarding 28: So `val f : t -> int = <fun>` not `t -> 'a -> int` as one might expect?

Comment: The `function`  keyword only works with one argument, this is not specially related to 28: `let zero_default = function Some n -> n | None -> 0`

Comment: Oh of course, I forgot. It's been some time since I wrote my last Ocaml... Thanks for the clarification edit.

Comment: Great explanations! It's a little surprising that argument-less constructors can have a wildcard argument in pattern matches. I'm really liking Dune's default of turning all warnings into errors now!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example for warning 5:

```
# let f a b = a + b;;
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# ignore (f 3);;
Warning 5: this function application is partial,
maybe some arguments are missing.
- : unit = ()
```

Warning 6 is disabled by default. If you enable it, it's easy to produce:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml -w +6
        OCaml version 4.06.1
# let f ~a = a * 10;;
val f : a:int -> int = <fun>
# f 3;;
Warning 6: label a was omitted in the application of this function.
- : int = 30
```

The rest are beyond what I can figure out without looking at compiler sources. Maybe an expert or two will show up who can give examples for them.